# Visual Basic warning

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm getting this 3 warnings. I wanted to know any way to fix it, thanks in advance!

Warnings:

Warning 1   Variable 'Id_Utilizador' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.   C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\Portaria\Portaria_Programa\Portaria_Programa\frmAdmin_NewEdit.vb 332 37  Portaria_Programa

Warning 2   Variable 'Id_Modulo' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.   C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\Portaria\Portaria_Programa\Portaria_Programa\frmAdmin_NewEdit.vb 332 60  Portaria_Programa

Warning 3   Variable 'DadosSai' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.    C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\Portaria\Portaria_Programa\Portaria_Programa\frmRel_EntradasSaidas.vb    222 37  Portaria_Programa

Code:

```
Private Sub NovoAcesso()

    Dim Id_Utilizador
    Dim Id_Modulo

    Dim Count

    If (cmbUtilizadores.Text <> "") Then

        If (cmbModulos.Text <> "") Then

            Cn.Open(cStringCon)
            Rs.Open("Select count(id_utilizador), id_utilizador from acessos_utilizadores where nome_utilizador like '" & cmbUtilizadores.Text & "'", Cn)

            Count = Rs.GetRows

            Rs.Close()

            If (Count(0, 0) > 0) Then

                Id_Utilizador = Count(1, 0)

                Rs.Open("Select count(id_modulo), id_modulo from acessos_modulos where nome_modulo like '" & cmbModulos.Text & "'", Cn)

                Count = Rs.GetRows

                Rs.Close()

                If (Count(0, 0) > 0) Then

                    Id_Modulo = Count(1, 0)

                    Rs.Open("Select count(id_acesso) from acessos_acessos where id_utilizador = " & Id_Utilizador & "", Cn)

                    Count = Rs.GetRows

                    Rs.Close()

                    If (Count(0, 0) > 0) Then

                        Msg = "O utilizador seleccionado já dispõe de um acesso."

                    End If

                Else

                    Msg = "Seleccione um módulo da lista."

                End If

            Else

                Msg = "Seleccione um utilizador da lista."

            End If

            Cn.Close()

        Else

            Msg = "Seleccione um módulo da lista."

        End If

    Else

        Msg = "Seleccione um utilizador da lista."

    End If

    If (Msg = "") Then

        Cn.Open(cStringCon)

        Cn.Execute("Insert into acessos_acessos(id_utilizador,id_modulo) " & _
                   "values (" & Id_Utilizador & ", " & Id_Modulo & ")")

        Cn.Close()

        ActGrid = 1

    End If

    Count = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Turn on Option Strict

Comment: You you really should define what what type your variables are. As things are, the compile thinks that you're declaring them as objects which need to be instantiated. If they're not, then using them before this then you'll probably get a null reference exception and the compiler is smart enough to spot this. So. As @Plutonix says - turn on option strict and it will highlight errors in your code that you've missed. Listen to Plutonix - he knows a LOT about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values `Id_Utilizador` and `Id_Modulo` might not have a value when you use them.  (The value `DadosSai` isn't in this code, though it sounds like it carries the same risk.)

This is because you're not *always* assigning a value to them.  To illustrate, consider this simplified version:

```
Dim SomeValue
If SomethingElse = True Then
    SomeValue = SomeOtherValue
End If
UseTheValue(SomeValue)
```

What would this code do if `SomethingElse` isn't `True`?  Nothing would ever have been assigned to the variable and it could easily break the function that's using it.

Either initialize your variables with default values or ensure that all logical paths assign values to them before they are used.

Comment: Thanks for the help, im kinda new to visual basic ;)

Comment: @TiagoTurella: Glad I could help.  As you get more practice you'll likely find ways to reorganize your code a little bit to make things like this easier to spot.  Your nested `If` blocks can probably be inverted to a series of pre-condition checks that may be easier to read.  Over time you may get some use out of some standard refactoring patterns: http://refactoring.com/catalog/  Also, as a side note, look up something called "SQL injection" and the use of parameterized queries to avoid it.  Currently your code is wide open to that vulnerability :)